# Question about using DBAccess

Tags: c#, t-sql, dbaccess

I need to use dbaccess to to write a sql database to a dataset in c#. I am not quite sure how to do this. Does anyone know of any good tutorials or have any advice on how to do this? Let me know if you need more info from me. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Just so I understand you clearly, are you saying you want to access a database in C# and get the data in a DataSet? If so, what database? What does the table in the database look like?

Comment: Yes, I have a databse in sql server. Its not a very big db. It has four tables. What more do you need to know?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the nigh-canonical example:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
{
    connection.Open();

    var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

    var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

    var dataSet = new DataSet();

    adapter.Fill(dataSet);
}
```

"connectionString" is the provider specific string which enables the system to connection to your database. If you don't know what this should be, here's a good place to start: [Connectionstrings.com](http://Connectionstrings.com).

Once you're ready to move to the next level beyond this, look at Entity Framework or NHibernate. HTH.

Comment: So, another way i have been shown is to use: _dba = DBAccess ("server=server1;database=database;user=user;password=password")

Comment: Yeah, it looks like DBAccess is an object that takes a connection string as a constructor argument (the "server=server1" stuff is a connection string). I'm not familiar with the DBAccess object per se; I don't think it's part of the .Net Framework proper. But if it helps you, then by all means use it.

Answer (score 0):

This ate the link you can start of:

[C# Station ADO.NET](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson01.aspx)

[ADO>net c#](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/Catalog0560__ADO.Net.htm)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090.aspx)

Regards... All this tutorial helps and easy to learn..